# An issue of mismatching input signal and network inputs when creating neural network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have an issue in building neural network with MATLAB, I have created neural network with input layer of 16 and output 
layer of 16 also as mentioned in the code below, and also created the neural network initial configuration. but when 
I run the command of configuration `net = configure(net,inputs_ele,output_ele);` I get an error of

```
Error using network/configure (line 134)
The numbers of input signals and networks inputs do not match.
```

However input signal is of size (16,1) and network input of same size !!

```
%initialize random synapse weights with a mean of 0
        inputs = 16; 
        inputs_ele = randn(16,1);               %Inputs elements 
        output_ele = randn(16,1);                   %Output elements
        N_layers = 2;      %Number of layers 
        bias = randi([0 1],N_layers,1);  %bias (Number of layers x 1)
        input_connect = randi([0 1],N_layers, inputs);  %input connect (Number of layers x entries)
        layer_connect = randi([0 1],N_layers, N_layers); 
        N_outputs = 1; 
        output_connect = randi([0 1],N_outputs, N_layers);       %output connect (1 x N_layers)

       %Creat network
        net = network(inputs,N_layers, bias, input_connect,layer_connect,output_connect );
        net.layers{1}.size = 16
        net.layers{2}.size = 16
        % hidden layer transfer functionnet
        net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'satlin';
        net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'logsig';

        %Configure Neural network 
        net = configure(net,inputs_ele,output_ele);
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue by justifying the length of the input data following the length of inputs layer length.